# Reading block by block from big matrix

Tags: java, matrix, block

Heaving a matrix *M* of size *nxn*. Divided that M into subMatrix of size *bxb*. For example, if the *n = 16* and *b = 8*, then I have *4* subMatrix of size *8x8*. here is the implementation of that function is working fine.

```
 public static int[][] getAcutalBlock(int[][] mat, int row, int col, int number) {

    /* mat is orignal big matrix of size nxn
     row is starting index for the block i
     col is staring index for the block *
     number is representing block ID either first block, second block or ... 
    */

    int[][] block = new int[blockSize][blockSize];
    int eRow = row + blockSize;
    int eCol = col + blockSize;

    if (number == 0) {   // it is for first block
        for (int i = row; i < eRow; i++) {
            for (int j = col; j < eCol; j++) {
                block[i][j] = mat[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    else if(number == totalBlocks-1){ // it is for last block
        for (int i = row; i < eRow; i++) {
            for (int j = col; j < eCol; j++) {
                block[i - blockSize][j - blockSize] = mat[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    else if (isEven(number)) { // if the number is even
        for (int i = row; i < eRow; i++) {
            for (int j = col; j < eCol; j++) {
                block[i - blockSize][j] = mat[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    else { // if the number is odd
        for (int i = row; i < eRow; i++) {
            for (int j = col; j < eCol; j++) {
                block[i][j - blockSize] = mat[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return block;
}
```

But the problem is that it is not dynamic. if the *b* is changed then how to read intermediate blocks except *first* and *last* block? I want to make it generic for any number of *n* and any number of *b*.
Any tutorial or code sample will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question but I'll give it a try.

If I understand this correctly the number is the representation of which sub-matrix you want to access and the *col*- and the *row*-variables are the respective position in that matrix. So a representation of the four submatrices would be something like

```
0 | 1
------
2 | 3
```

With the 9x9-matrix looking like

```
0 | 1 | 2
----------
3 | 4 | 5
----------
6 | 7 | 8
```

If this is the case then I'd only make a two-nested for-loop like you've done already for *number == 0* but adding so that the *mat*-matrix retrieved the desired element through a calculation containing starting-index for the matrix and the current index in the loop. The code could look something like this

```
int[][] block = new int[blockSize][blockSize];

// to get how many matrices that are put next to each other on a row
int numbersOfSubMatricesPerSide = mat.length / blockSize; 

// starting position for this matrix column wise
int colStart = (number % numbersOfSubMatricesPerSide) * blockSize; 

// starting position for this matrix row wise
int rowStart = (number / numbersOfSubMatricesPerSide) * blockSize; 

// fill the sub-matrix
for (int i = 0; i < blockSize; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < blockSize; j++) {
        block[i][j] = mat[colStart + i][rowStart + j];
    }
}

return block;
```

So say if we had *b = 10* and *n = 30* and we wanted to create matrix #1 (middle top) then we'd get *colStart = blockSize* and *rowStart = 0* meaning that for our block we'd collect the data from the mat-matrix with start at (blockSize, 0) and ending in (2 * blockSize - 1, blockSize - 1) 
=> starting at (10, 0) and ending in (19, 9).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Dear Cerise Charizard, It is working for me, thanks for your efforts.